# Convert file names containing dates to QQ-YYYY format and insert as a column for N excel files in R

Tags: r, excel, string, filenames

I have a number of xls files which I have downloaded off the web and I wish to convert these file names to QQ-YYYY and save these strings as a new column. This date field is not currently in the original xls file. Please note some of the files I am interested in will have full month names sometime and others will be abbreviated i.e. Oct & October

```
> pricingFiles
[1] "Apr 2018 ASP Pricing File 031318.xls"           "Apr 2019 ASP Pricing File 032219.xls"          
[3] "Jan 18 ASP Pricing File updated 030218.xls"     "Jan 2019 ASP Pricing File - updated 052919.xls"
[5] "Jul 2018 ASP Pricing File updated 052919.xls"   "Jul 2019 ASP Pricing File 091119.xls"          
[7] "Oct 18 ASP Pricing File updated 052919.xls"     "Oct 2019 ASP Pricing File 092519.xls"
```

As we can see above I wish to convert the date string piece before ASP Pric...... to QQ-YYYY and then save this to a new column in a dataframe i.e.

Apr 2018 ASP Pricing File 031318.xls ->  Q2-2018 and then insert this as a date column in the DF upon reading into R.

Please note that each xls files being on different rows numbers and I have a function defined which I plan to use in the skip argument

```
skip=header_begins[i]-1
```

My code looks as follows:

```
startDate <- 2018
endDate <- as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))

# FUNCTION DEFINITION TO FETCH 2018 TO 2019 CROSSWALK AND ASP PRICING ZIP FILES
fileFinder <- function(yearsVector)
{
  for (i in yearsVector)
  {
    message(paste0("Getting data for ", i))
    tryCatch({
      webpages <- read_html(paste0("https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Medicare-Fee-for-Service-Part-B-Drugs/McrPartBDrugAvgSalesPrice/", 
        i, "ASPFiles.html"))
      r <- webpages %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% grep(c("\\Crosswalk.zip$|\\ASP-Pricing-File.zip$"), 
        ., value = TRUE) %>% gsub("apps\\/ama\\/license.asp\\?file=\\/", 
        "", .) %>% paste0("https://www.cms.gov", .)
      return(r)
    }, error = function(e)
    {
      # TODO
      return(NA)
    })
  }
}

# CREATE LIST TO STORE URLs
urls <- list()

# PASS DATE RANGE TO THE CMS ZIP FINDER FUNCTION
urls <- lapply(startDate:endDate, fileFinder)

# CONVERT LIST OF URLs INTO VECTOR
urls <- unlist(urls, recursive = F)

# CREATE FUNCTION TO DOWNLOAD FILES FROM CMS.GOV
download.cms <- function(urls, refetch = TRUE, path = ".")
{
  dest <- file.path(path, basename(urls))
  if (refetch || !file.exists(dest)) 
    download.file(urls, dest)
  dest
}

# DOWNLOAD THE CROSSWALK ZIP FILES
sapply(urls, download.cms)

# UNZIP ALL FILES
for (i in dir(path = ".", pattern = "*.zip$")) unzip(i)

# CREATE A LIST OF ALL EXCEL FILES IN THE DIRECTORY
listExcelFiles <- list.files(".", pattern = c("\\.xls$|\\.csv$|\\.xlsx$"))

# RETAIN EXCEL FILES THAT ARE CROSSWALK FILES
crosswalkFiles <- listExcelFiles[grepl("ASP NDC-HCPCS", listExcelFiles) & !grepl("508 version", 
  listExcelFiles)]

# RETAIN EXCEL FILES THAT ARE PRICING FILES
pricingFiles <- listExcelFiles[grepl("ASP Pricing File", listExcelFiles) & !grepl("508 version", 
  listExcelFiles)]

# CREATE A LIST OF FILES TO DELETE 
# TBC

# SINCE EACH FILE BEGINS ON DIFFERENT ROWS, DEFINE FUNCTION TO DETECT HEADER LINE
detect_header_line <- function(file_names, column_name)
{
  header_begins <- NULL
  for (i in 1:length(file_names))
  {
    lines_read <- readLines(file_names[i], warn = FALSE)
    header_begins[i] <- grep(column_name, lines_read)
  }
}

# FIND THE FIRST ROW FOR EACH FILE
header_begins <- detect_header_line(myExcel, "Short Description")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the substring and use `as.yearqtr`

```
library(zoo)
as.yearqtr(sub("^(\\w+\\s+\\d+).*", '\\1', pricingFiles), "%b %Y")
```